# What is the proper term for ipaddress/hostname:port

Tags: ipv4, ipv6

What is the proper term for (example) hostname.tld:433 (hostname:portnumber)?

It is not just hostname, and it is not really a URL either :) same goes for 10.0.0.1:3306 etc.

Comment: This is not on-topic here, but what you're looking for is probably "URI".

Comment: A URI includes the mechanism used to access the resource, for example http: or ftp:, and as such doesn't really answer the question. URI schemes are [defined and documented](http://www.iana.org/assignments/uri-schemes/uri-schemes.xhtml).  See [this W3C document](http://www.w3.org/TR/uri-clarification/) for further clarification.

Comment: It's "socket" although a "endpoint" is in vogue these days.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_socket.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47488910/whats-the-difference-between-endpoint-and-socket/47490978

Answer (score 35, accepted):

IP address and port pair is called, [Socket Address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_socket)

Pair of socket addresses (10.0.0.1:123, 192.168.0.1:123) may also be called 4-tuple or 5-tuple if the protocol is specified as well (10.0.0.1:123, 192.168.0.1:123 UDP)

Comment: This is more true in the programming/systems world and not always as relevant in networking. In networking the IP address and port/protocol are generally distinct and specific values, and not used as a single value.

Answer (score 11):

I've been writing a lot of network code over the years, and the word "**endpoint**" seems to be the term for "a specific port on a specific IP address".

Have a look at the Boost documentation as well as the Microsoft documentation:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__tcp/endpoint.html

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbx2eya8(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbx2eya8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47488910/whats-the-difference-between-endpoint-and-socket/47490978 -- an endpoint is a more general term than a socket; there are are non-TCP endpoints.

Comment: Note that "endpoint" has a different meaning in web services. In web services, an endpoint is a complete URL.

Answer (score 5):

According to the [DOM/Web API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/host) it is simply `host`.

> The host property of the URL interface is [...] the hostname, and then, if the port of the URL is nonempty, a ':', and the port of the URL.

You can see this in a browser console:

```
url = new URL('http://example:8080/path')
url.hostname  // "example"
url.host      // "example:8080"
```

Answer (score 2):

If your use case covers the optional 'authentication' section, then this would be called an "authority".

> [A URI] comprises:
>
> ...
>
> - An authority part, comprising:
>
>   - An optional authentication section of a user name and password, separated by a colon, followed by an at symbol (@)
>   - A "host", consisting of either a registered name (including but not limited to a hostname), or an IP address. IPv4 addresses must be in dot-decimal notation, and IPv6 addresses must be enclosed in brackets ([ ]).
>   - An optional port number, separated from the hostname by a colon
>
> ...
>
> [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Syntax)

It is formalized in [RFC 3986 - Uniform Resource Identifier (URI): Generic Syntax](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.2)

> The authority component is preceded by a double slash ("//") and is
> terminated by the next slash ("/"), question mark ("?"), or number
> sign ("#") character, or by the end of the URI.
>
> ```
> authority   = [ userinfo "@" ] host [ ":" port ]
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I would call generically describe (IPAddress, Port) as an IP Service.

If used in DNS context, then look up [DNSSRV](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2782) records.

If used in Socket context, then it is a [Socket Address](https://github.com/apple/swift-nio/blob/2.26.0/Sources/NIO/SocketAddresses.swift#L60-L72).

Another context could be use in a regular expression used in filtering Flows.

Or use in router or firewall in an access-list.