# Does socket address include transport protocol (http://)?

Tags: ipv4, ipv6, ip-address, internet, transport-protocol

Let's say I have the following: `http://ip_addr:port`

This is supposedly called the socket address (see sources below), but I can't find a conclusive answer anywhere if the transport protocol (`http://`) is included in this term.

Does socket address include the transport protocol?

**Sources**

A simple Google Image search of "socket address" yields many results, none having the protocol included.

From [Network socket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_socket) (Wikipedia), it suggests socket address does include `http://`:

> socket address, which is the triad of transport protocol, IP address, and port number.

The question [What is the proper term for ipaddress/hostname:port](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/9429/56477) 's selected answer does not include transport protocol.

Comment: HTTP is an application-layer protocol. A transport-layer protocol is like TCP or UDP. Unfortunately, questions about protocols above the transport layer are off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [sf] for a business network.

Answer (score 1):

`http://ip_addr:port` is a URL. It includes the TCP socket `ip_addr:port` (since HTTP uses TCP in the transport layer/L4).

A port only makes sense in the context of a transport-layer protocol like TCP or UDP. However, the L4 protocol is often just implied and not explicitly stated.